# English as a second language - Is it acceptable to edit spelling and grammar?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spelling, grammar

This question refers specifically to questions posed by individuals that are clearly using English as a second language. It does not refer to people who are making minor mistakes in their native language.

I don't want to seem pedantic, but I see some good questions that are written in English as a second language, with some detracting grammar and spelling mistakes.

Comment: I found and read that other question that you refer to. It deals with a different situation.

Comment: No it's not. The answer is exactly the same: "Spelling and grammar corrections are acceptable - anything that improves a question is a good thing". It doesn't matter a tiny bit *why* the original question was posted with mistakes. Lazy person, second language, drunk person... we shouldn't really care.

Comment: While I agree that the answer is substantially similar, the question and its context are different. Someone looking for that answer for this situation, might not find it based on the other question. I think it would be sufficient to be able to say that the questions are related, rather than duplicates.

Comment: In this site, having the same answer justify closing as duplicate. Both questions stay, but only one should have answer.

Comment: So, by that logic, the following questions would be duplicates:
"What is the sum of 1 and 1?"
"How many time periods are there in a rugby match?"
"What number does the following lyrical phrase end with? 'Tea for ...'"

Comment: I think I can see the intention of this approach to "duplicate". I'm inclined to believe, however, that it would be better to delete one of the questions (maybe this one, since it was the latter of the two) and edit the other question to be less specific and more general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, yes it is.

As long the fix is not like adding a comma or two, it's okay. These types of edits make posts much more easy to read and for people to understand the question or answer. There are times where some confusion can lead up to a lot of trouble... But anyways, it is allowed but don't fix the post if they only forgot one or two things. Those edits are kinda useless...

Comment: I might risk small spelling corrections in a title, as that is like the "front door" inviting you to read the complete question.

Comment: As long the edit is not too minor or useless, it's okay

Comment: As English as second language user I feel it is needed to correct language use, not just that of others but also that of myself. But I guess that many of the people you think about have English as third or later language or have just a little bit of English. And do not forget that many native speakers write worse than many 'ESL' and those also require updating their questions and answers.